# How to add column sum (with condition) as new column?

Tags: r, data.table, aggregation

I have a data.table with the following shape:

```
    Order_ID Item Amount
1:        a   i1      1
2:        a   i2      2
3:        a   i3      3
4:        b   i1      2
5:        b   i3      1
6:        c   i2      3
7:        c   i3      4
```

So, there are three orders with some items. What I would like to do with one data.table command is to add the total number of items of an order and give it out in each row:

```
    Order_ID Item Amount Total
1:        a   i1      1     6
2:        a   i2      2     6
3:        a   i3      3     6
4:        b   i1      2     3
5:        b   i3      1     3
6:        c   i2      3     7
7:        c   i3      4     7
```

I get there by creating a new data.table an merge it with the first one. But I thought that there has to be a more elegant way. :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `df$Total <- ave(df$Amount, df$Order_ID, FUN = sum)`?

Comment: Check the answer below as it provides the actual data.table syntax. I just wanted to make sure that's what you needed.

Comment: Please read some of these vignettes https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To utilize the efficiency of `data.table` it helps to use something like:

```
dt[, Total := sum(Amount), by=Order_ID]
#    Order_ID Item Amount Total
# 1:        a   i1      1     6
# 2:        a   i2      2     6
# 3:        a   i3      3     6
# 4:        b   i1      2     3
# 5:        b   i3      1     3
# 6:        c   i2      3     7
# 7:        c   i3      4     7
```